# Калькулятор Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Помогите прописать правильно калькулятор.
На странице оформления заказа необходим калькулятор, который будет считать сколько не хватает денег (общая сумма заказа) до бесплатной доставки.

В моем случае файл:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/quickcheckout/cart.twig
```

отталкиваемся от этого значения: `{{ total.text }}` (правда тут есть еще знак валюты)
Допустим, бесплатная доставка начинается от 500 грн.

Что я должен прописать в контроллере и какое новое значение указать в виде?

Контроллер:

```
<?php 
class ControllerExtensionQuickCheckoutCart extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $data = $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');
        $data = array_merge($data, $this->load->language('extension/quickcheckout/checkout'));
        $data['error_warning'] = '';

        if ($this->cart->hasProducts() || !empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
            if (!$this->cart->hasStock() && (!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning'))) {
                $data['error_warning_stock'] = $this->language->get('error_stock');
            }
        }

        // Totals
        $this->load->model('setting/extension');

        $total_data = array();                  
        $total = 0;
        $taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();

        $total_data = array(
            'totals' => &$totals,
            'taxes'  => &$taxes,
            'total'  => &$total
        );

        // Display prices
        $data['totals'] = array();

        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
            $sort_order = array(); 

            $results = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('total');

            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get('total_' . $value['code'] . '_sort_order');
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($this->config->get('total_' . $result['code'] . '_status')) {
                    $this->load->model('extension/total/' . $result['code']);

                    $this->{'model_extension_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data);
                }
            }

            $total_data = $totals;

            $sort_order = array(); 

            foreach ($total_data as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $total_data);

            foreach ($total_data as $total) {
                $text = $this->currency->format($total['value'], $this->session->data['currency']);

                $data['totals'][] = array(
                    'title' => $total['title'],
                    'text'  => $text
                );
            }
        }

        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $this->load->model('tool/upload');

        $data['products'] = array();

        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product_total = 0;

            foreach ($products as $product_2) {
                if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
                    $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
                }
            }

            if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
                $data['error_warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_minimum'), $product['name'], $product['minimum']);
            }

            $option_data = array();

            foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
                if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                    $value = $option['value'];
                } else {
                    $upload_info = $this->model_tool_upload->getUploadByCode($option['value']);

                    if ($upload_info) {
                        $value = $upload_info['name'];
                    } else {
                        $value = '';
                    }
                }

                $option_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $option['name'],
                    'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
                );
            }

            if ($product['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_cart_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_cart_height'));
            } else {
                $image = '';
            }

            // Display prices
            if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            // Display prices
            if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $total = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity'], $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $total = false;
            }

            $recurring = '';

            if ($product['recurring']) {
                $frequencies = array(
                    'day'        => $this->language->get('text_day'),
                    'week'       => $this->language->get('text_week'),
                    'semi_month' => $this->language->get('text_semi_month'),
                    'month'      => $this->language->get('text_month'),
                    'year'       => $this->language->get('text_year'),
                );

                if ($product['recurring']['trial']) {
                    $recurring = sprintf($this->language->get('text_trial_description'), $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['recurring']['trial_price'] * $product['quantity'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']), $product['recurring']['trial_cycle'], $frequencies[$product['recurring']['trial_frequency']], $product['recurring']['trial_duration']) . ' ';
                }

                if ($product['recurring']['duration']) {
                    $recurring .= sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_description'), $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['recurring']['price'] * $product['quantity'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']), $product['recurring']['cycle'], $frequencies[$product['recurring']['frequency']], $product['recurring']['duration']);
                } else {
                    $recurring .= sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_cancel'), $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['recurring']['price'] * $product['quantity'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']), $product['recurring']['cycle'], $frequencies[$product['recurring']['frequency']], $product['recurring']['duration']);
                }
            }

            $data['products'][] = array(
                'key'        => isset($product['key']) ? $product['key'] : $product['cart_id'],
                'thumb'     => $image,
                'name'      => $product['name'],
                'model'     => $product['model'],
                'option'    => $option_data,
                'recurring' => $recurring,
                'quantity'  => $product['quantity'],
                'stock'     => $product['stock'] ? true : !(!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning')),
                'reward'    => ($product['reward'] ? sprintf($this->language->get('text_points'), $product['reward']) : ''),
                'price'     => $price,
                'total'     => $total,
                'href'      => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
            );
        }

        // Gift Voucher
        $data['vouchers'] = array();

        if (!empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
            foreach ($this->session->data['vouchers'] as $key => $voucher) {
                $data['vouchers'][] = array(
                    'key'         => $key,
                    'description' => $voucher['description'],
                    'amount'      => $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'], $this->session->data['currency']),
                    'remove'      => $this->url->link('checkout/cart', 'remove=' . $key)
                );
            }
        }

        // All variables
        $data['edit_cart'] = $this->config->get('quickcheckout_edit_cart');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/quickcheckout/cart', $data));
    }

    public function update() {
        $this->load->language('extension/quickcheckout/checkout');
        $json = array();

        if (!empty($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
            foreach ($this->request->post['quantity'] as $key => $value) {
                $this->cart->update($key, $value);
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['remove'])) {
            $this->cart->remove($this->request->get['remove']);

            unset($this->session->data['vouchers'][$this->request->get['remove']]);
        }

        if (!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
            $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
        }

        if (!$this->cart->hasStock() && (!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning'))) {
            $json['error']['stock'] = $this->language->get('error_stock');
        } else {
            $json['error']['stock'] = '';
        }

        // Validate minimum quantity requirements.          
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product_total = 0;

            foreach ($products as $product_2) {
                if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
                    $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
                }
            }       

            if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
                $data['error_warning_minimum'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_minimum'), $product['name'], $product['minimum']);
            } else {
                $data['error_warning_minimum'] = '';
            }               
        }

        if ($this->cart->getTotal() < $this->config->get('quickcheckout_minimum_order')) {
            $json['error']['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_minimum_order'), $this->currency->format($this->config->get('quickcheckout_minimum_order'), $this->session->data['currency']));
        } elseif (isset($data['error_warning_minimum'])){
            $json['error']['warning'] = $data['error_warning_minimum'];
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае проще и быстрее всего будет добавить в админке, где-нить в настройках, новое поле. В это поле указывать значение пороговой суммы для бесплатной доставки и сохранять его, например, в таблице setting. Потом в нужном контроллере доставать значение и работать с ним.

```
$this->config->set(name, value); // конфиг сеттер
$this->config->get(name, value); // конфиг геттер
```

Comment: Значение я достану с базы, а код контроллера можете подсказать?

Comment: ostatok = porog - total